# How to add chapters into mp4/mkv file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line-interface, metadata, video-editing

Currently i'm using **MKVToolNix** for my needs which is fine but i would prefer some *CLI* also.
As far as i know **ffmpeg** supports chapters management.

Comment: ;FFMETADATA1 - header
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1 - forcing ffmpeg use seconds
START=0 - beginning 
END=60 - ending
title=chapter \#1 - title itself
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1
START=61
END=120
title=chapter \#2
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1
START=121
END=140
title=chapter \#3

Comment: ffmpeg -i INPUT -i FFMETADATAFILE -map_metadata 1 -codec copy OUTPUT - Reinserting edited metadata information from the FFMETADATAFILE file

Comment: Isn't `mkvtoolnix` a frontend for the command line tool `mkvmerge`?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1320389/updating-mp4-chapter-times-and-names-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 15):

The ffmetadata format allows you to add chapters to a file.

Have a look at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Metadata-1 for an example.