# ffmpeg: input metadata map file syntax

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, metadata

I'm trying to use ffmpeg with many metadata parameters and I'd like to know if there's any way to **pass metadata using a file**, minimizing cli command length.

I've seen in ffmpeg help and documentation that there are an option:

```
-map_metadata outfile[,metadata]:infile[,metadata]  set metadata information of outfile from infile
```

Nevertheless, I haven't been able to find how to use it, I couldn't find any example.

> In other words, I'm looking for some syntax which could provide me the
>   following change in my ffmpeg execution:

**From this**

```
ffmpeg -i input -metadata metadata1='asdf1' -metadata metadata2='asdf2' ... -metadata metadataN='asdfNN' [output]
```

**To this**

```
ffmpeg -i input -map_metadata filemetadata.txt [output]
```

File filemetadata.txt

```
metadata1='asdf1'
metadata2='asdf2'
...
metadataN='asdfN'
```

> The reason why I need to minimize command line length is that if
>   you launch **FFmpeg in a docker container** , ENTRYPOINT / CMD / command
>   (in compose) has a limitation in number of parameters / string length.
>   I need to pass many parameters, and I'd like to avoid creating a bash
>   file with FFmpeg call, for example, copy it and execute with docker
>   exec.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Check this Stackoverflow link for an answer to your question:

[How to add chapters into mp4/mkv file using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415660/how-to-add-chapters-into-mp4-mkv-file-using-ffmpeg)

Briefly:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -i meta -map_metadata 1
```

where the file "meta" has the tags, and the initial line of ";FFMETADATA1".

For instance:

```
;FFMETADATA1
major_brand=M4A
minor_version=512
compatible_brands=isomiso2
artist=Herman Melville
album=Moby Dick
```